# How do I prototype on a div?

Tags: javascript

It's becoming increasingly more and more difficult to find advice on how to use javascript outside of various frameworks.  This is somewhat infuriating.... but whatever.

I want to extend a div via prototype, tacking on a bunch of extra functionality, in pseudo code, I'm hoping to do the following...

```
<div id="wrapperDiv">
  <div id="buttonDiv"/>
</div>

<script>
function ExtraFeatures(){
  this.clickMyButton = function(){
     alert("clicked");
  }
  //the idea here is that **this** will reference the div itself after the prototype is set
  this.childNodes[1].onClick = this.clickMyButton;//
}

var wrapperDiv = document.getElementById("wrapperDiv");
wrapperDiv.prototype = new ExtraFeatures;

//so, here I call it manually, but it's also been set as the onclick callback in the child div
wrapperDiv.clickMyButton();

</script>
```

I'm pretty sure this is possible, but the above code is not doing what I want it to do.

TIA.

Comment: Have you also thought about event bubbling? You are firing the event on a child when the parent is clicked - the event will bubble to the parent and creates an endless loop.

Comment: @Majid, this is not an actual code sample, just the idea behind what I want to have happen, in principal.  The click will be captured and used by the child element, when I'm done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A prototype is used before an object is created and the new object is created from the prototype.  Once the object exits, you have to just add methods/properties to it.  So, if you want to add methods to a DOM object, you can just add them in a function.

I would suggest this instead:

```
addMyExtraFeatures(obj) {
    obj.clickMyButton = function () {
        alert("clicked");
    }
  //the idea here is that **this** will reference the div itself after the prototype is set
  obj.childNodes[1].onClick = obj.clickMyButton;//
}

var wrapperDiv = document.getElementById("wrapperDiv");
addMyExtraFeatures(wrapperDiv);

//so, here I call it manually, but it's also been set as the onclick callback in the child div
wrapperDiv.clickMyButton();
```

Comment: are you sure about your initial statement? I was under the impression that you can prototype anything at any time and it will change in-place to take on the additional features you give it.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel - You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/FzsqL/.  The first button has a click handler assigned to the prototype and it doesn't do anything.  The second button has a click handler assigned to the object as a direct method on the object and it does work.

Comment: If you want to extend an existing object, you just add methods or properties directly to it as I've shown in my code example.  The prototype is used at object creation time as the template for the new object, not after it's already created.

Comment: yeah, I think this is the closest I'm going to get to what I want.  I do wish I could refer to the dom object via *this* in my extended object, but this will do.

Answer (score 2):

Before you go extending DOM objects, best read these articles by Kangax:

- [What’s wrong with extending the DOM](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/)
- [Extending built-in native objects. Evil or not?](http://perfectionkills.com/extending-built-in-native-objects-evil-or-not/)

You should note that an "extend the DOM" strategy was adopted by the Prototype.js library but has now been abandoned, so please think very carefully before implementing it.

You should probably also take note that while javascript is by far the most popular way to script web-based documents, the W3C DOM standards and specifications were (and still are to a large extent) written to be language neutral. That is, they can be implemented in any language.

It therefore also makes sense to not assume any particular inhertance scheme. So you should not assume that all browsers or user agents support prototype inheritance (some in common use do not), nor that those that do support it will continue to do so in a way that is compatible with how it is implemented today.

Answer (score 1):

Bind the function to the "this" scope:

```
Function.bind = function(fn, bind) {
  return function() {
    // apply(variable to use as "this" in the function, arguments)
    return fn.apply(bind, arguments);
  };
};

// and if you want to have it as a prototype fn...
Function.prototype.bind = function(bind) {
  // probably a nicer way to do it, but okay
  return Function.bind(this, bind);
}


// dun dun dun
this.childNodes[1].onClick = this.clickMyButton.bind(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
HTMLDivElement.prototype.clickMyButton = function(){
   alert("clicked");
}
```

Comment: AH! of course, prototype works on the "class" and not on the instance.  So... what is the approach (or is there one) for just extending the specific instance?

Comment: Specific instance? You just add properties there, nothing new. With your function you can `ExtraFeatures.call(wrapperDiv)`, maybe that is what you actually need.

Answer (score 0):

Are you opposed to jQuery? This can be done easily with jQuery library and extending its functionality. e.g.

```
(function($){
  $.fn.extend({
    makeBlue: function(){
      return this.filter('div').each(function(i,e){
        $(this).css('background-color','blue');
      }).end();
    }
  });
})(jQuery);

var $div = $('#mydiv');
$div.makeBlue();
```

Comment: I am opposed to jQuery :)  I realize I'm preaching to the unconvertible, and this is entirely a matter of taste, but just LOOK at that code sample above (yours).  It's the ugliest bunch of bulls**t I've ever seen! It's as though someone went out of their way to take a really lovely and elegant language (Javascript) and manipulate it into an unholy mess.  I appreciate your suggestion, and am sure it works, but if it works, that means there must be a more straight forward and simpler way to just do it in native JS. Check back here to find out what it is, when I uncover it! :)

Comment: _"It's becoming increasingly more and more difficult to find advice on how to use javascript outside of various frameworks."_ - the _first_ sentence in the question...

Comment: nnnnnn: Agreed, though I didn't read in tot hat as "absolutely no way I'm doing it without a framework", just merely a strong preference. -- @Dr.Dredel: Javascript and elegant; interesting concept. I personally use it out of pure necessity, and look forward to HTML5 and not needing it. ;p But to each his/her own.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but I thought HTML5 was just a bunch of new methods and features in javascript. I've been using the language for 15 years, and I guess at some point, elegance == familiarity. I've talked to people who think Objective C is not an ungodly jumble of crap... so clearly, there's no accounting for taste! :)

Comment: @Dr.Dredel: More about things like form validation/controls (I'm basically excited about the new tel/email/url/search controls, and the required/placeholder/pattern attributes (places where JS would normally be supplemental). It's disappointing though since HTML5 is a long way from complete.

Comment: @Dredel—HTML5 is a lot more than that, it includes a bunch of new elements and attributes, bundles in much of what was DOM 0 and adds new features that the working group participants think are necessary. The group seems to be largely driven by authors of some popular script libraries, which I think is a bad thing. Where are the representatives for **browser users**? Heaven forbid that users' opinions should matter.

Comment: Dr. Dredel, you'll soon find out that creating cross-browser code for DOM/XHR without the help of a normalizing library yields *much* uglier code than that. Brad's code has a lot of cruft too, could be much simpler: https://gist.github.com/1210689

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want to implement kind of subclassing here.
If 'yes' then the `prototype` is wrong property for what you want to achieve.

Here is code that injects ExtraFeatures object into prototype chain of particular DIV element:

```
<div id="wrapperDiv">
  <div id="buttonDiv" >ddd</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

  var wrapperDiv = document.getElementById("wrapperDiv");

  var ExtraFeatures = {
    extraFoo : function(){ alert("clicked"); }
  };

  ExtraFeatures.__proto__  = wrapperDiv.__proto__;
  wrapperDiv.__proto__ = ExtraFeatures;

  wrapperDiv.extraFoo();

  //for( var p in wrapperDiv )
  //  console.log(p);

</script>
```

But `__proto__` is not supported by IE :)

Comment: You might be more interested in Mozilla's deprecation of [__proto__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) then. @c-smile — it is usually not a good idea to recommend non–standard, deprecated features, particularly where they are only supported by a small number of browsers.

Comment: @RobG: Thanks for your recommendation of what to recommend.

Comment: @RobG: My sample is just an idea of what should be done to achieve the goal. Author of the topic is responsible for final decision. In any case it is good to know the difference between `__proto__` and `prototype` for anyone reading this discussion.